# Plone 4 Deletion Permission (security tab under ZMI)

Tags: plone

I have the Intranet / Extranet workflow enabled on a Plone 4.2 site, I have removed most of the members permissions (so they can only view).

I created an account and started to add some content but even though I have the "Owner" role permission "Delete portal content" enabled (under mysite.com/manage_access) however my test user is unable to delete anything, which is great... However they cannot delete anything they have created either (I need them to be able to delete content they create).

I have searched on Google but am getting results related more to accomplishing bulk user actions using python scripts.

Basically what I want is that if you created the content, you are able to delete it, if you did not create it you cannot delete it.

Currently I have the second part setup and that's working, but for some reason it seems to be ignoring the "Owner" role, even on content I have created.

I can't find any other permission that I could tick that would indicate ability to delete content you own, can anyone lend any insights? Thanks.

EDIT:

To expand on the problem, it seems if I create a folder and then create content under it, that content is not deleteable, but if I then create a folder, and content within the folder I created, although the folder is not deletable the content within it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by installing [collective.deletepermission](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.deletepermission/) and adding the necessary "Delete Objects" permission to the "Owner" role in the ZMI under manage_access

Comment: You can also look at redturtle.deletepolicy, wich is not adding a new permission.